# ¿Cómo consumir un json web service con android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, json, webservice

¿Cómo poder consumir un json webservice con android studio?

Para poder llenar un listview con el JSON.

Comment: Primero debes tener tu WebServise de lado del servidor ya sea en PHP, PYTHON, .NET u otros luego utilizar la libreria volley para consumir recursos web y JSON

Comment: SI tengo mi Web Service hecho en java con el cual genero el JSON , lo que necesito saber es como hacer el llamado del json y poder obtener sus valores para llenar mi ListView. ¿Se puede usar otra librería aparte de volley?

Comment: claro de otra forma es HttpRequest

Comment: para usar httprequest ¿es necesaria la librería ksoap2

Comment: te agrego un tutorial : http://www.androidauthority.com/use-remote-web-api-within-android-app-617869/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Retrofit, que es un cliente Web para Android. Te pueden servir las siguientes páginas.

1. http://www.tempos21.com/web/blog/introduccion-a-retrofit/
2. https://stories.devacademy.la/mi-primer-app-con-retrofit-y-android-ac61a8954a2c

Para consumir un servicio unicamente utilizarias algo como esto:

```
@GET("servicio/ws/obtenerUsuarios/")
    Call<UsuarioDTO> buscarUsuarios();
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo basado en los enlaces mencionados, de esta manera quedará grabado en caso los enlaces dejen de funcionar y aumentas la calidad a tu respuesta :D